# Busca valor Input Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, input

tenho o seguinte campo na página "index.php":

```
<input type="hidden" id="exemplo" value="<?php $varExemplo; ?>">
```

Gostaria de pegar o valor deste campo em uma outra página utilizando jQuery.

```
var exemploIndex = $("#exemplo").val();
```

Seria algo assim? Ou precisaria declarar o form também?
Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Primeiro, faltou um `echo` para definir o atributo `value` do campo. Segundo, utilizar jQuery para pegar o valor em outra página? Como assim? Você está submetendo esse formulário para um arquivo PHP e quer pegar o valor nesse arquivo?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Anderson, o echo eu só não coloquei ali no exemplo, mas no código está presente. Então, antes de submeter o form, há um "select" que recebe um parâmetro da página que eu preciso enviar essa variável(exemplo), a minha ideia inicial era mudar esse "select" da forma que eu quisesse, porém ele é utilizado em mais páginas então daria "caca", e essa "página", eu acabei me expressando mal, é um arquivo JS com algumas funções dentre elas a que eu preciso receber esse valor, para comparar com o valor do "select" mencionando anteriormente. Valeu!

Comment: Ainda muito confuso. O que é esse `select`? Quais são esses arquivos?

Comment: Hehehe, esse select é um input no qual mostra alguns produtos, ele é gerado a partir de uma função que está nesse arquivo JS. Eu tenho duas possibilidades na minha fraca lógica, uma em que eu possa enviar o valor junto a esse select, ou que eu possa apenas enviar e receber um valor naquela função vindo de um input qualquer que não fosse o select.

Comment: Se todos os arquivos citados são JS e todos estão incluídos na página que possui o formulário, sim, seria algo como você colocou na pergunta: `$("#exemplo").val()`.

Comment: Legal, então eu apenas usaria o "id" do input? Não preciso declarar o form em que esse input pertence? Desculpe a ignorância...

Comment: Sim, apenas o `id`, pois o `id` define um elemento único na página inteira. Não há como existir dois elementos com o mesmo `id`, então não precisa informar onde o elemento está localizado.

Comment: Beleza Anderson, vou tentar aqui, muito obrigado pela ajuda e paciência!

Comment: @LucasMWP Se quer enviar o valor desse `input="hidden"` para uma outra página, vc precisa de um `<form method="post">` e fazer um _submit_, e na outra página receber esse campo com `$_POST['nome_do_campo']`. Não seria isso?

Comment: @LucasMWP E ainda dar um `name` ao campo em vez de um `id`.